# Unix to run commands repeatedly on shell without using crontab

Tags: unix, shell

Say if I need to run a command `checkstatus --jobnumber 12345` to check the job status. The command prints out the info to standard output. Is there any way to run this command on shell repeatedly every minute? I wanted to see the latest job status.

Comment: why you dont wan't to use crontab?

Comment: I think the idea is to run it in the foreground. `crontab` would run the command in the background, and even if it could run it in the foreground it'd be overkill, IMHO. This is exactly what `watch` is for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Also [watch(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch)

Comment: this is the best way imho. `watch -n 60 'command to run'`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small bashscript that would do that:

```
#!/bin/bash 

while : 
do
        checkstatus --jobnumber 12345;
        sleep 60;
done
```